# Image won't appear in JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, jframe

I've created GUI for my application using Netbeans' GUI Builder. I am trying to display a `JFrame` containing a `JLabel` with an image, and I can't get the `Image` to display.

My generated code :

```
private void initComponents() {
        //...
        jLabel1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
}
```

And my class code:

```
public class GUIWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    BufferedImage myPicture;

    /** Creates new form GUIWindow */
    public GUIWindow() throws IOException {
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("images/logo.png"));
        initComponents();
        this.add(jLabel1);

    }
}
```

but I still don't see an image ... **(path to the image file is fine)** its sth like:

```
my-project :
  /build
  /dist
  /images/logo.png
  /nbproject
  /src (here I have all my source files)
  /build.xml
  /manifest.mf
```

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) and this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use like this

```
URL imgSmartURL = this.getClass().getResource("your image path");
jLabel1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imgSmartURL), JLabel.CENTER);
```

Comment: I dont think the OP needs that, his folder is located in his projects directory not in the jar itself

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: Ok, I see... I tested it but I still don't see the image

Comment: +1, for using getClass().getResource(...), the nice way to access Application Resources.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp  Unless I am mistaken, the `logo.png` will become an embedded resource by the time this app. is deployed.  Then it will be easiest to add it into the Jar and use `getResource(String)`.  If it needs to be changed, might as well change it now.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this instead.

```
    JLabel dice1 = new JLabel();
    ImageIcon one = new ImageIcon("dice/1.png");

    //set dice1 position
    dice1.setLocation(20, 100);
    dice1.setSize(115, 115);
    dice1.setIcon(one);
    gamepanel.add(dice1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using netbeans you can directly add an image to a jLabel by setting properties. `Right click on the jLabel -> properties -> icon -> (if it's external image) import to project(upload your image) -> ok` .
It'l be added into your jLabel.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'd suggest you copy the image in a  seperate folder(images).
2. Then use   `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/A.png");`

I believe there's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876742/netbeans-imageicon-not-displaying)

Answer (score 0):

private ImageIcon imageIconPrint =

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image/print.gif"));
```

create button and add follwing code:

jbtCanada.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    jlblFlag.setIcon(imageIconCanada);

  }

});
```

this would help i think