# Icon on the Label makes the program not running

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, label, icons

So, I am creating a GUI interface for the project via Netbeans (using it is a requirement). Everything is fine until I add an Icon for a label. The generated code is below:

```
jLabel25 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

jLabel25.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/mycompany/sostarnyba/images/map.png")));

jLabel25.setText("");
```

I add the icon exactly as the person in this question shows it: [Netbeans ImageIcon not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876742/netbeans-imageicon-not-displaying)
Except my app does not run at all.

When the icon is removed, everything runs, but when it is added it does not. The error is: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by putting not a full path within the project but the absolute path in your computer starting from /Users